# \textheight reduced by one inch?

Tags: margins

I have the following in my preamble (actually it is in a file \include d):

```
% One inch margins, NO HEADERS
\setlength{\textwidth}{468pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{630pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0in}
\setlength{\headheight}{0in}
\setlength{\headsep}{0in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt}
```

So the text should be about 8.75 inches (modulo 72 vs 72+pts/in).  However, the body of the text in the resulting document is about 7.75 inches high instead and there is an extra inch of whitespace at the bottom of the page.  Something is overriding my dimensions and I can't figure out what.  Using `\typeout` I can see that all the above dimensions have the values that I gave them.

Using Tex Live on Mac OS 10.9.5.  I'm using letter paper.

(I vaguely recall that something like this used to happen a LONG time (decades) ago and it had to be corrected in printer configuration files (oog).  But I haven't messed with a printer config file in a long time.  The TeXlive setup on my previous mac never had this problem...)

All of the dimensions print as specified except \textheight.  I am not changing any other lengths relevant to the page layout.

I have used this format file for years without seeing this.  So my hypothesis is that I missed some configuration parameter when I installed TeXLive...

Comment: Are you using Letter paper or A4 paper?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! That's a text height of about 8.72 inches. If you get 7.75, then probably you have some setting that changes it.

Comment: Or the document is scaled down when printed.

Comment: The reference point for those settings is 1in in from the top and left edges of the paper. (unless you have set `\hoffset` and `\voffset` to -1in)

Comment: Yes.  See the comment about "one inch margins"?

Comment: It's not a printing artifact - the whitespace is there when I view the PDF onscreen.

Comment: How can you measure on the screen that the textbody is 7.75 inches? What is your output if you load the lipsum package and then add `\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{\rule[-7.75in]{4pt}{7.75in}}\lipsum` at the begin of your document?

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the default paper size was set to a4 instead of letter, and somehow I had not noticed it since I installed the macports TeX packages several months ago.  (Guess I was not writing much!)

I was surprised that:

- it took me so long to figure out exactly what the problem was.  The very first comment above should have made me at least verify that the paper format was correct, but since I've been using this more than six months, I guess I figured that couldn't be it.
- I never could figure out a way to fix it in the macports TeXLive configuration.  There must be something in a file somewhere, but every hint I found on the interweb didn't work.
- The macports TeXLive I installed did not include tlmgr, and the texconfig that it included did not work - it would start and then exit immediately.  I didn't bother trying to debug it.

I ended up uninstalling the macports version and installing MacTex, which is working great and includes some additional features (which I may or may not ever use).

Thanks to all those who commented, and sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I removed any trace of MacPorts from my machines long ago. `;-)`